# index and range of matching characters in string ios

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring

Is there any built in function in `NSString` to do the following?

I have an `NSString` called `str1` with text `@"dental visit"` and `str2` with text `@"vis"`.

I want to get the starting index of the matching character of `str2` in `str1` and the range of the match only if the `str2` is completely matched.

For the above I should get index as 7 and range as 3.

Comment: Please scan the reference docs before asking a question like this. A quick scan of the docs for `NSString` would have answered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `NSString`'s method `rangeOfString`:

```
NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:str2];
NSUInteger location = range.location;   // gives 7 per example
NSUInteger length = range.length;       // gives 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[str1 rangeOfString:str2];
```

This will return `{NSNotFound, 0}` if `str2` is not found within `str1` (or if `str2` is empty: `@""`).  It will raise an invalid argument exception is `str1` is `nil`.  Otherwise, if `str2` is found within `str1`, it will return an `NSRange` struct with the range in which `str2` was located in `str1`.